# Why write() doesn't fail when I delete the file on write?

Tags: c, linux

I have a question that why write() system call still succeed to write something after I have deleted the target file from shell?

When I delete the file after the first several success writes, I was expecting to see write() fails but it doesn't and I don't know where does it write to.

Can anyone explain this to me, thanks!!

### Here's my testing sample code:

```
int fd = open ("./test.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0666);
if (fd == -1)
    error_and_exit ("open() failed");

ssize_t written = 0;
char buf[] = "apple\n";

while (true)
{
    printf ("perform write...\n");
    written = write (fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (written <= 0)
        error_and_exit ("write failed");
    printf ("=> wrote %d bytes\n", written);
    printf ("sleep %d...\n\n", SLEEP_TIME);
    sleep (SLEEP_TIME);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A file is not physically deleted (at the inode level, if the file system has inodes) until the last open file descriptor closes on the file, even if there are no name references left for the file (because its last name has been unlinked, aka deleted).  This is how temporary but anonymous files are created for POSIX (Unix) systems, by creating the file and then deleting its name.

Note that if you have a daemon process that keeps a log file open, the daemon is likely to keep writing to the old file (not the new one) and the space won't be released until the daemon does terminate (or, more accurately, closes the file descriptor for the old log file).

Comment: This is also why deleting all the gigantic unrotated log files doesn't free up `/var` until you kill everything that had those files open

Comment: @mkb: I was writing up the second paragraph as you supplied the comment.

Comment: Please replace 'inode' by 'meta-data' or similar.  There are file systems which do not use inodes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: _Some Unix-style file systems such as ReiserFS omit an inode table,..._ from [inode / wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)

Comment: @Andreas: modified answer.  Thanks for the information; I live (if SO counts as life) and learn.

Answer (score 2):

Linux keeps a counter for all files. If you open a file then it is increased. When you delete a file then the counter is decreased by one, and if the counter is zero then the file is actually considered deleted.

So when your program opens the file the counter is increased from one to two, then when you delete the file the counter is decreased to one again. It will not be decreased again until you close the file, and when you do the counter will be zero and the actual file will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you rm'd the file, subsequent attempts to 'find' the file (to open it for reading, etc.) will fail. Your existing process will continue to have access to the file until it either terminates or closes the file. The info written to the file will be accessible to your process until that time. After that, the info is not accessible (except by 'extraordinary' means - search for 'recover a deleted file in linux unix' for details).